# array cannot be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate rellai here using math.pow . While everything else in the formula can be plugged in, rel_tt is a numpy array between 0 and 1. I have generated that using np.linspace. Is there a way to pass the list of rel_tt numbers to calculate the rellai ranges rather than plugging it individually? I get an error only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars. I think it is expecting a single value for rel_tt rather than an array.

Here is what I have tried:

```
rel_tt = np.linspace(0, 1)
rellai = math.pow((1.001 - rel_tt) / (1 - 0.6), 0.5)
print(rellai)
```

Comment: `rel_tt` is not a `list`, it is a `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? run that formula on all the numbers in the array? What is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is to run the formula on all the numbers in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.pow` can't take an array.  But if you use exponentiation instead it works:

```py
import numpy as np
import math

rel_tt = np.linspace(0, 1)
rellai = ((1.001 - rel_tt) / (1 - 0.6)) ** .5
print(rellai)
```

Output:

```
[1.5819292  1.56572015 1.54934153 1.53278791 1.51605355 1.4991324
 1.48201807 1.46470377 1.44718234 1.42944616 1.41148713 1.39329663
 1.37486549 1.35618387 1.3372413  1.31802651 1.29852742 1.27873104
 1.25862332 1.2381891  1.21741194 1.19627398 1.17475573 1.1528359
 1.13049113 1.10769571 1.08442122 1.06063612 1.03630525 1.01138922
 0.98584368 0.95961833 0.93265585 0.90489034 0.87624547 0.84663198
 0.81594443 0.78405669 0.75081588 0.71603358 0.67947309 0.64083014
 0.59970231 0.55553798 0.50754511 0.45451252 0.39441251 0.32332772
 0.23134478 0.05      ]
```

Comment: That is a very smart solution. Thank you.